# Api deployed in GCP not working: The server encountered an error and could not complete your request

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I deployed an API  to GCP that s working locally, but I received the following error:
Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.

I have tried with multiple apis that work fine locally but won t work when deployed.

I was trying to deploy my api to GCP

Comment: What does your log say? To view your log, go to console.cloud.google.com, select your project and then select 'log' from the side menu